# Any reason to not wire a circuit this way?

Tags: range, circuit, hood

[image]

Other than it being unorthodox and maybe confusing, is there any reason to not wire a circuit up this way? Canadian Electrical Code if it matters.

The Box closest to the panel needs an always hot and a switched power source. One for a range hood and one for undercabinet lighting. If a receptacle here is a problem it can also be two hardwires coming out of a junction box with a knockout. The other receptacle on the far right can also be hardwired instead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are both the range hood and the various lights involved all switched together?

Comment: The range hood must always remain on so that it can be turned on and off by it's own on unit switch.

Comment: Looks fine, but you need a GFCI. Since GFCI's don't come in split outlet types, plus you can't hide the GFCI behind the range hood, get a GFCI breaker. Don't forget to label the outlets - the GFCI breaker will come with stickers.

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine but; Check your code, the first duplex may be required to be a AFCI unless it is in the panel. This would be dictated by location of the duplexes and light. My next concern is why are you using #14 inplace of #12 feeding the duplex outlets. I am assuming each of the cables also has an earth ground (not the neutral) in the cable.

Comment: Yes its 14/2 and 14/3 with ground.

Comment: Do you mean AFCI or GFCI? Or, possibly both? Also, if it's a 15A breaker, #14 wire is perfectly acceptable. NM-B cabling (which the 14/2 & 14/3 nomenclature indicate) always count the number of current carrying wires and ground is understood to be in there, too.

Comment: Well, it's evidently in a kitchen, so you have to be sure that the outlets are **not** part of the required 20A countertop circuits (where I belive CEC and NEC are aligned) for 15A to be acceptable. If it's strictly for Fan & Lights and that requirement is met by other receptacles it's fine to be 15A, I believe.

Comment: First of all, yes its 2 and 3 wire + ground wire. In Canada residential we use 14AWG protected by 15A breakers for general receptacles and for ALL lighting. The only time you would have to use 12AWG would be for 20A kitchen counter circuits or for a circuit needed to be 20A for a specific appliance.  The overall circuit length is short and the Range Hood only draws 3A, and since it will also be used for lighting the circuit its capped at 15A by code, no concerns with voltage drop and the #14. It is not part of the kitchen countertop circuits.

Answer (score 1):

### This is fine, although I'd hardwire the undercabinet lights if at all practical

What you propose is fine, as the half-switched receptacle doesn't serve any countertop surfaces (just the range hood and a lighting load) and thus doesn't need to be a GFCI.  You may wish to pull a 14/4 instead of a 14/3, or use individual wires in an ENT conduit ("smurf tube") if that is permitted in Canada, in order to provision for a remote switch for the range hood, though.